# Как добавить полученный после преобразований столбец к изначальному фрейму?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

Есть изначальный фрейм данных:

|  | Name | Ноябрь | Декабрь | Февраль |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Алексей | 15 | 10 | 15 |
| 1 | Алексей | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | Андрей | Empty | Empty | Empty |
| 3 | Андрей | 15 | 25 | 15 |
| 4 | Алексей | 15 | 15 | 10 |
| 5 | Андрей | 25 | 10 | 45 |

Для дальнейших преобразований с помощью `pd.drop` из него были удалены некоторые строки и был получен новый столбец.

Столбец `idx` содержит изначальные значения индексов:

|  | Name | Ноябрь | Декабрь | Февраль | num | idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Алексей | 15 | 10 | 15 | Ноябрь | 0 |
| 1 | Алексей | 10 | 10 | 10 | Ноябрь | 1 |
| 2 | Андрей | 15 | 25 | 15 | Февраль | 3 |
| 3 | Алексей | 15 | 15 | 10 | Ноябрь | 4 |
| 4 | Андрей | 25 | 10 | 45 | Февраль | 5 |

Как мне теперь можно добавить полученный новый столбец к изначальному фрейму данных?

|  | Name | Ноябрь | Декабрь | Февраль | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Алексей | 15 | 10 | 15 | Ноябрь |
| 1 | Алексей | 10 | 10 | 10 | Ноябрь |
| 2 | Андрей | Empty | Empty | Empty |  |
| 3 | Андрей | 15 | 25 | 15 | Февраль |
| 4 | Алексей | 15 | 15 | 10 | Ноябрь |
| 5 | Андрей | 25 | 10 | 45 | Февраль |

Comment: значения индексов соответствующих строк в двух фреймах совпадают? Можете привести примеры данных вместе со значениями индексов?

Comment: После удаления строк производилась переиндексация

Comment: Ну тогда тем более нужны примеры данных с индексами )

Comment: Скорее всего вам придётся отказаться от переиндексации. Или найти такое решение, при котором значения индексов во втором Фрейме сохранятся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
res = df1.join(df2.set_index("idx")[["num"]])
```

результат:

```
In [140]: res
Out[140]:
      Name Ноябрь Декабрь Февраль      num
0  Алексей     15      10      15   Ноябрь
1  Алексей     10      10      10   Ноябрь
2   Андрей  Empty   Empty   Empty      NaN
3   Андрей     15      25      15  Февраль
4  Алексей     15      15      10   Ноябрь
5   Андрей     25      10      45  Февраль
```